# Profiling ruby/rails method Names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, metaprogramming, benchmarking

I am using ruby/rails `Benchmark` module for quite some time.

Every time I have to benchmark a method I have to write code like this:

```
Class BenchMarkTest
  def self.method_to_benchmark()
       # code here
  end  
end
```

**Usage:**

```
t1 = Benchmark.realtime {
  BenchMarkTest.method_to_benchmark()
}

puts "Time Taken:#{t1.inspect}"
```

I always have to wrap method/block inside Benchmark module.

Is there any way, gem or library, I can provide method names and get the benchmark output without disturbing/writing any code?

For example:

I have an array of method names:

```
methods_to_benchmark = ["method_to_benchmark", "method2"]
```

Whichever method names are in above array will be benchmarked at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

We are using newrelic so newrelic method tracers solved my problem.

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/ruby/ruby-custom-metric-collection#method_tracers

Thanks